# Where can I find the dumps of the older tries?

Tags: discussion

I would like to save content from them, but I can't find them on the A51. Maybe it is because I don't have a really high reputation there currently.

Could somebody (maybe a 10k+ A51 user) get a link to the old dumps?

Comment: Just make sure you don't use ones that I've already salvaged ;)

Comment: Related: http://meta.ai.stackexchange.com/questions/1124/can-i-steal-a-question-from-a-closed-site

Comment: @Mithrandir Thanks, I do this with my *NI*, and I use the search before that :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you need 10K on Area 51 to see the data dumps; they seem to work even if you're not signed in. At the top, there's a little banner that says this, with the appropriate link where I have bold:

> The AI site didn't have enough activity during the beta, and has been closed. You can download the **data dump of all questions here**.

Here are the links to the two previous AI proposals that I know of:

- [The original](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6607/artificial-intelligence), the subject of [this SE blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/no-artificial-intelligence-in-area-51/). Possibly [the first closed SE site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279893/include-the-child-metas-of-closed-sites-in-their-data-dump#comment907488_279910), and only the main site's data (not the meta) is available. **[Direct download.](http://sstatic.net/area51/datadumps/122010%20Artificial%20Intelligence.zip)**
- [The second try](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57719/artificial-intelligence). This one has both meta and main in the data dump. **[Direct download.](http://sstatic.net/area51/datadumps/022014%20Artificial%20Intelligence.zip)**

Also, there was a [closed Machine Learning proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41738/machine-learning), **[direct data dump download here](http://sstatic.net/area51/datadumps/082013%20Machine%20Learning.zip)**. [Another one](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/26434/machine-learning), slightly older, is indeed missing the data dump, and unfortunately it [probably doesn't exist](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25354/136466).